# Finding exact cause of my deleted question

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I earned the [Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=480850) for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315745/why-does-nstableview-setobjectvalue-to-the-current-mixed-value), which has since been removed.

Searching MSO, I found one [somewhat-related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132670/156412) that indicates that I should be able to find out *why* the question was deleted, or at least whether it was a community or moderator decision to delete.  However, the links on the deleted question's page only provide a link to a FAQ of **possible** reasons.

As the OP, how can I find out definitively why my question was removed (aside from finding the closing moderator)?

Comment: To the badge issue: all badges (except tag badges) are eternal.

Comment: [How do “badges” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) Read the section *`What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?`*. You do not lose badges unless it is a tag badge.

Comment: Looks like the question was deleted automatically; no deleter was logged. The system cleans out low-vote, low-views posts over time; yours was deleted after a year without votes and without many views (237 at the current count).

Comment: @MartijnPieters what's the cutoff for "low-views"?

Comment: @Richard: See the post Anna links to in her answer: *viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5*

Comment: Note that the answer to this question has changed significantly since the original answer was posted. The way it currently works is explained in the FAQ, linked above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have 10,000 reputation and can see the deleted question, you unfortunately can't find out the exact deletion reason short of posting here on meta and asking. This comes up periodically, and I personally think we should allow askers to see their own deleted questions if they at least have the link to them. Showing deleted stuff on profiles is a bigger debate.

With all that said, your question was removed automatically because it fit the [deletion criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/155160): it had zero score, no answers or comments, low views, and was over a year old.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree about allowing OPs to see their own deleted questions if they have a link.

Comment: Just curious, I saw on one of the deleted posts that you had left a comment for the user to read the faq. It was a nice welcome message for new users but the comment and deletion timestamps were same. Can the user still see the full comment other than the shortened message on the inbox?

Comment: @Siva On an answer, yes. On a question... to be honest, I'm always a bit hazy on that. I _think_ those comments would disappear from the inbox?

Comment: I remember seeing your comment on an answer and not on a question. I have no idea if comments on deleted questions disappear from inbox or not. I haven't experienced it yet.

Comment: At the time, I didn't realize this could happen; is there any way for me to retrieve the body of the question so that I can try to re-work it as a new question (obviously in a way that would generate more responses)?

Comment: @Richard I'll email it to you.

Answer (score 7):

Your question was removed most likely because it didn't have any activity/attention for a long period of time. See [FAQ.Deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)

> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other
>   questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no
>   significant activity over a very long period after being asked.

And once you earn a [regular badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/208592), you earn it forever.

Comment: Agreed, this is most likely, especially coupled with Tumbleweed.  However, I was under the impression that the exact reason is available to the poster.